# Managing custom directives

Tags: angularjs

I need to make some custom directives. Every tutorial shows building the directive relative to the controller where it is to be used. I'm sure this is not the right way if you need to put it into another controller.

I have a global controller. Should I put my directives there? I also have a Utilities factory and inject this into my controllers(this keeps everything tidy and manageable). Do directives work the same way?

How do you manage multiple directives and where do you put them?

Comment: Add your directives in separate file like directives.js and use those directives in many views or controllers.

Comment: Do you just add them to your index.html  <script src="directives.js"></script>?

Comment: yes, right.  directive.js should be included after your app.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your directives in separate file like directives.js and use those directives in many views or controllers.

directive.js should be included after your app.js

For example if your app.js is like:

```
var app = angular.module('myangularapp', ['ngResource']);
```

then your directive.js should be like:

```
app.directive('confirm', function(ConfirmService) {
});

app.directive('alert', function(AlertService) {
});
```

Comment: you should use this syntax : angular.module('myangularapp', ['ngResource']); and then angular.module('myangularapp').directive('confirm', function(ConfirmService) {..});